# How to print out more than 9 in the function?

Tags: c, integer, digits

```
#include <stdio.h>

void numDigits(int count, int number) {
    while (number > 0)
    {
        number = number / 10;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe number of positive intergers is %d.\n", count);
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    numDigits(count, number);
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints out '9' for numbers longer than 9 digits. If user enters 0123456789 it should equal 10 but this code instead displays '9'.

Comment: You start the number with zero! Try 1234567890 instead

Comment: When you divide `01` (in 9th iteration) by `10` then it will return `0`. So, in the next iteration `number` becomes `0` and loop terminated.

Comment: To consider leading zeros you need to read the number as `string`.

Answer (score 3):

You're saving the number as an `int`, and that doesn't record the leading `0`. Whether the user enters `0123456789` or `123456780` is all the same for the program, as both are stored as `123456789`. Instead, you should read it in as a string:

```
char buf[20];   // holds a maximum of 20 digits, different amounts can be specified
```

And then later do

```
scanf_s("%19s", buf);   // include one less than the same length that was specified in buf's definition
```

You won't even need a function to operate on an integer and count the digits, just use `strlen` for that:

```
printf("\nThe number of positive intergers is %d.\n", strlen(buf));
```